# Best way to come up with predictive model for events in multivariate time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I have a dataset for events occurred in past year and other measurement around event for past one day, so if I have 10 events in past year I would have 10 days data just before the event for all the measurements. Measurements are more than 100. What kind of model I can use to predict the events? or what kind of algorithms I should try which  are recommended by experts. Data is at seconds interval or I can aggregate it to any other frequency.

Comment: your question confuses me. Perhaps you can post your data or a simile

Comment: @IrishStat I will try to produce sample data for same. If you can point out what part in question is confusing I will try to explain it better. Thanks